# Oracle PL/SQL data access package code generator

Tags: oracle, database-design, code-generation, data-access-layer

as many of you whose job is PL/SQL development on Oracle might have experienced in their career, it is common to create packages in order to handle the data access layer on a specific table. I mean, given a table 'employee' is a wide common practice to create a package 'da_employee' ('da' stands for 'data access') that implements routines such as ins() in order to insert a row into employee, del() for deleting a row, upd() for updating, lock() for locking, ..., I could go on...

The content of the package might vary on the basis of the needs and the personal choices, but it is likley to state that once the structure of a data access package is designed for a table, the hundreds more table I plan to create in my schema might need a package based on the same design.

At this point I could state it is possible to auto-generate such a kind of package using the metadata stored in the DB and a tamplate of the package itself.

I guess I'm not the first who have come to this conclusion, so I'm wondering if there are such code generation solutions around, either commercial or free.

Comment: I think that TAPI's (table APIs) in general are a poor choice and you'd be wise to avoid them. your APIs would be better suited to a a given process. e.g. updateEmp(...) what if we wanted to update one of the columns, and sometimes 3 of them? do you overload, or have some logic that says if the input is null, don't update that column (and if so your api will either be overly long or use dynamic SQL which will be poor)

Comment: Is it common practice? It might be if you're operating a web-service that only requires single row inserts/updates (deletes?) but I do everything in bulk... This should be fairly easy to write for yourself should you need to do it. It'll look horrible though; why not just write the package you need? There will always be additional things/checks that you want to do.

Comment: Some links for discussion: http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2010/06/23/tapi-vs-xapi/

Answer (score 0):

The CodeGen utility is no longer available at Toadworld. I am now looking into offering alternatives for TAPI (and more generally data access layer) generation on the PL/SQL Challenge site (plqlchallenge.com). Rick, I would be interested to talk to you about yours - feel free to contact me at steven@stevenfeuerstein.com.

Regarding the question of whether to use a TAPI or not: I believe it is most important to focus on the fundamental principles first and then seek out the optimal solution.

The key principle, for me, is to avoid repetition of SQL statements in my app, and consequently to make it easier to optimize, maintain and enhance those statements. For this reason, a data access layer is critical. Some of us build apps that perform DML on individual tables, and so we find TAPIs useful. Others do not and prefer "XAPIs" (transaction APIs).

These days, I write packages that contain parts of both - and generate as much of it as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

https://code.google.com/p/tapig/

I looked at it briefly.. but it had an issue becuase I have table names with _ in them